# Listview dentro de un item de RecyclerView no mantiene la selección de un ListViewItem

Tags: android, c#, xamarin

Tengo un RecyclerView con una gran cantidad de filas (preguntas), en cada fila hay un control Listview con máximo 4 items (que son alternativas) y un botón para enviar alternativa.

El problema es que cuando selecciono un item del Listview, hago scroll y luego regreso al mismo item, la selección desaparece. A pesar de forzar la selección del Listview item desde código, el layout de este no cambia. Esto sucede al ejecutarse el método `OnBindViewHolder`.

Este es el adapter de preguntas:

```
public class QuestionsAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter
{
    public static MainViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }
    Context context;

    public QuestionsAdapter(Context context, MainViewModel viewModel)
    {
        ViewModel = viewModel;
        this.context = context;

        ViewModel.Questions.CollectionChanged += delegate
        {
            var activity = context as Android.Support.V7.App.AppCompatActivity;
            activity.RunOnUiThread(delegate { NotifyDataSetChanged(); });
        };
    }

    public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        var question = ViewModel.Questions[position];
        var questionsHolder = holder as QuestionsViewHolder;

        var alternativesListView = questionsHolder.Alternatives;
        alternativesListView.ChoiceMode = ChoiceMode.Single;
        var adapter = new AlternativesAdapter(alternatives, context);
        alternativesListView.Adapter = adapter;

        //  Something selected?
        if (question.Content.SelectedAlternativePosition == -1)
            questionsHolder.SendAnswerBtn.Enabled = false;
        else
        {
            var view = adapter.GetView(question.Content.SelectedAlternativePosition, null, null);

            //  Intenté esto también:
            view.Background = context.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.alternative_background_selected);

            //  Así lo estoy forzando actualmente
            alternativesListView.PerformItemClick(view, position, adapter.GetItemId(position));
        }

        //  ...
    }

    public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        var itemView = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.QuestionItem, parent, false);
        var vh = new QuestionsViewHolder(itemView);
        return vh;
    }

    public override int ItemCount => ViewModel.Questions.Count;

}
```

Su ViewHolder:

```
public class QuestionsViewHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder, AdapterView.IOnItemClickListener
{
    // ...
    public readonly Button SendAnswerBtn;
    public readonly NonScrollableListView Alternatives;

    public QuestionsViewHolder(View view) : base(view)
    {
        //  ...
        SendAnswerBtn = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnEnviar);
        Alternatives = view.FindViewById<NonScrollableListView>(Resource.Id.alternativesListView);

        Alternatives.OnItemClickListener = this;
    }

    #region IOnItemClickListener implementation

    public void OnItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id)
    {
        //  Change state
        view.Selected = true;

        SendAnswerBtn.Enabled = true;
        ViewModel.Questions[AdapterPosition].Content.SelectedAlternativePosition = position;
    }

    #endregion IOnItemClickListener implementation
}
```

Y este es el adapter de alternativas:

```
public class AlternativesAdapter : BaseAdapter<Alternative>
{
    List<Alternative> alternatives;
    Context context;

    public AlternativesAdapter(List<Alternative> alternatives, Context context)
    {
        this.alternatives = alternatives;
        this.context = context;
    }
    public override int Count => alternatives.Count;

    public override long GetItemId(int position) => alternatives[position].ID;

    public override Alternative this[int position] => alternatives[position];

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        var view = LayoutInflater.From(context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.AlternativeItem, null, true) as Button;
        view.Text = alternatives[position].Description;
        return view;
    }
}
```

El layout de las alternativas es este:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/alternative_background"
android:elevation="0dp"
android:clickable="false"
android:focusable="false"
android:stateListAnimator="@null" />
```

El xml del drawable selector que maneja los estados de selected.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/alternative_background_selected">
  </item>

  <item android:state_selected="false" android:drawable="@drawable/alternative_background_default">
  </item>

</selector>
```

Vale aclarar que ya he intentado incluso aplicarle el drawable `alternative_background_selected` desde código a la opción seleccionada pero la interfaz sigue sin reaccionar.